# Using enum as annotation

Tags: java

I have an enum :

```
public enum Vehicle {
  CAR,
  BUS,
  BIKE,
}
```

I intend to use these enum values as annotations : @Vehicle.CAR, @Vehicle.BUS, @Vehicle.BIKE. Does java allow me to define them as annotations ?

Comment: No, because annotations are interfaces, not values.

Comment: No. Only annotations can be used as annotations. Read the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html

Comment: 1. your code won't compile. 2. what's the reasoning behind your question, what's the benefit of doing so ?

Comment: @alfasin, yes it would not compile as-it-is, the code I gave was the end goal I wanted to achieve and my question was about does Java allow me to reach that end goal. I realized it's not. Coming to what's the benefit : I have the code which is already using the methods on this enum extensively. I am creating annotations which correspond to each of the elements of the enum. If there is a way I could use them as the annotation itself, I could avoid creating additional names for the annotations, otherwise i need to maintain the one-to-one mapping from enum elements to the annotations...

Comment: Continuing my previous comment: maintenance cost : if I add a new value to the enum I will have to make sure corresponding new annotation is created. Ability to avoid this extra maintenance is what I desire. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I asked what you're trying to achieve not how you're trying to do it or why does it fail. What's the motivation to have enum states as annotations ? what are you trying to accomplish ?

Answer (score 3):

No You can not do this. But if you want to use enum in annotation you can do like this

```
class Person {    
    @Presentable({
        @Restriction(type = RestrictionType.LENGTH, value = 5),
        @Restriction(type = RestrictionType.FRACTION_DIGIT, value = 2)
    })
    public String name;
}

enum RestrictionType {
    NONE, LENGTH, FRACTION_DIGIT;
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Restriction {
    //The below fixes the compile error by changing type from String to RestrictionType
    RestrictionType type() default RestrictionType.NONE;
    int value() default 0;
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@interface Presentable {
  Restriction[] value();
}
```

Comment: At least you should share the source of that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3020063/3665178

Answer (score 2):

You can't use enum as annotations. But you can add the enum as an element of the annotation.

The enum

```
public enum Priority { 
    LOW, 
    MEDIUM, 
    HIGH 
}
```

The annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface TestAnnotation {
    Priority priority() default Priority.MEDIUM;
}
```

The annotation usage

```
@TestAnnotation(priority =  Priority.HIGH)
public void method() {
      //Do something  
}
```